# Error when push a node app (Node-red) thru CF on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm facing the following message when I push a new version of node-red, thru CF:

> MacBook-Pro-do-Sergio-Gama:lab-gama sergiogama$ cf push Usando o
>   arquivo manifest
>   /Users/sergiogama/bluemix/node-red/lab-gama/manifest.yml
>
> Atualizando o app lab-gama na organização sgama@br.ibm.com / espaço
>   Demo como sgama@br.ibm.com... OK
>
> Usando a rota lab-gama.mybluemix.net Fazendo upload de lab-gama...
>   Fazendo upload de arquivos de app de:
>   /Users/sergiogama/bluemix/node-red/lab-gama Fazendo upload de arquivos
>   116.6M, 19771 Done uploading                COM FALHA Erro ao fazer upload do aplicativo. The resource file mode is invalid: File mode
>   '0555' is invalid.

Please help me to solve that.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please take a look at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/685 and check if you are experiencing a similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error and I fixed creating a .cfignore file with node_modules inside.
There is a problem when you try to upload your node_modules to bluemix.